# how to use file_put_contents function into loops?

Tags: php, json

I want to get multi images from their urls and I want to save them in a directory.
I've used `file_put_contents()` as you see.but it just puts one of the images.
Is it a better way to us this function in loops or is it another function to use instead of `file_put_contents()` in loop?

```
<?php
include "config.php";
//open ssl:
$arrContextOptions = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    ),
);
set_time_limit(0);

$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' . $name . '/media/';
$content = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
$json = json_decode($content, true);
//var_dump($json);die();


mkdir($name);
chmod($name, 0600);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 19; $i++) {
    $a = $json['items'][$i]['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
    $content = file_get_contents($a);
    file_put_contents($name . '/image.jpg', $content);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the filename to:

```
file_put_contents($name. '/image_'.$i.'.jpg', $content);
```

Then they will stop overwriting each other.

Comment: Glad I could help! All the best!

Answer (score 2):

Use file_put_contents($name. "/image$i.jpg", $content). You're now overwriting the same file so only one remains

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `FILE_APPEND` with purpose to store all images in one file:

```
file_put_contents($name. '/image.jpg', $content . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Or with purpose to create bunch of files you have to use `$i` in file name, like:

```
file_put_contents($name. "/image.$i.jpg", $content);
```